# inner join to find number of items in the same revision number

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have the following tables

```
tblMainequipment
asset_id   rev    equipment_name
123        0      box
123        1      box 
124        0      box 
125        0      bottle  

tblmainswablocation
asset_id   rev   swab_location
123        0     cover
123        0     base
123        1     cover
123        1     base
123        1     lock
124        0     cover
124        0     base
125        0     tube
125        0     cover
```

I did like to get the total count of swablocations for the maximum rev for a particular asset_id. For example, the total number of swab location for asset_id 123 rev 0 is 2 but for rev 1 its 3.  I have been trying to figure out for the past few hours but cant seem to find a solution. I am pretty bad with joins. The following shows the what i am trying to get,

```
query
asset_id   maxrev    #swablocation  equipment_name
123        1         3              box
124        0         2              cover
125        0         2              bottle
```

I use the following sql

```
SELECT MEQ.*
FROM tblMainEquipment AS MEQ 
INNER JOIN (Select asset_id, max(rev) as maxrev     
            From tblmainequipment  GROUP By asset_id)  AS groupmeq ON 
            (MEQ.asset_id = groupmeq.asset_id) AND (MEQ.rev = groupmeq.maxrev)
```

I am not sure how i can add the #swablocation into my query.

Comment: How are you defining #swablocation? Is this a count, an ID number?

Comment: that would be a count, i will edit my posting to make it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method that uses correlated subqueries:

```
select me.*,
       (select count(*)
        from tblmainswablocation as sl
        where sl.asset_id = me.asset_id
       ) as numSwabs
from tblMainEquipment as me
where me.rev = (select max(me2.rev) from tblMainEquipment as me2 where me2.asset_id = me.asset_id);
```

The advantage is that the outer query does not require aggregation.

Comment: i have tried this but it returns the total count of the swab locations from all the rev#, i would only need the swab locations from the maxrev
i got 5 swab locations for asset id 123

Comment: I manage to get it to work by adding one more line of code
'select me.*,
       (select count(*)
        from tblmainswablocation as sl
        where sl.asset_id = me.asset_id AND sl.rev = me.rev
       ) as numSwabs
from tblMainEquipment as me
where me.rev = (select max(me2.rev) from tblMainEquipment as me2 where me2.asset_id = me.asset_id)'

Answer (score 1):

You need a count and a group by

```
SELECT MEQ.asset_id maxrev, MEQ.maxrev, 
    count(blmainswablocations.swab_location), MEQ.equipment_name
FROM tblMainEquipment AS MEQ 
INNER JOIN (Select asset_id, max(rev) as maxrev     
        From tblmainequipment  GROUP By asset_id)  AS groupmeq ON 
        (MEQ.asset_id = groupmeq.asset_id) AND (MEQ.rev = groupmeq.maxrev)
Inner join blmainswablocations on MEQ.asset_id =  blmainswablocations.asset_id
Group by MEQ.asset_id maxrev
```

Comment: this query does not include tblmainswablocations

Comment: there is one part which i dun understand why you have count(tblmainswablocation.swab_location) without having a reference to the table in the first FROM

Comment: In a join all the columns can be referenced not only the columns in the "from" table